# When and how often does the EV_RXCHAR event fire (from WaitCommEvent)?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, events, serial-port

I've been digging through the [reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/SerialPort.cs,65c54d508b24bc24) for the .NET `SerialPort` and `SerialStream` classes, and have found that they fire their `DataReceived` events by waiting on `WaitCommEvent()`.

The event usually fires just once, when the serial port has received some amount of data. Usually when the event fires, transmission has finished: I only need to read once to get all of my data. However, sometimes the event finishes before all the data has been received. In this case, the event will fire a second time, and I can read the rest of my data then.

This leads me to the question: When exactly does the `EV_RXCHAR` event fire? Immediately after the first byte of data is received? After data has been received and some amount of time has passed without receiving any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained in more detail in the MSDN page on [Communications Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> For example, if you specify the EV_RXCHAR event as a wait-satisfying
>   event, a call to WaitCommEvent will be satisfied if there are
>   characters in the driver's input buffer that have arrived since the
>   last call to WaitCommEvent or SetCommMask.

So `EV_RXCHAR` will fire when one or more characters arrive. If you were to not read those bytes but instead call `WaitCommEvent` again immediately, it wouldn't fire again until more (new) characters arrive.